# DMA Memory to Memory mode is not working in STM32F103C8

Tags: c, embed, stm32, dma

I am trying to copy array using DMA MEM2MEM mode in STM32F103C8

But when i run this below code, the dest array still remains empty, no interrupt event fired

Please give me solutions or notice me if i missed any config, thanks very much

My code:

```
uint32_t source[MEMSIZE];
uint32_t dest[MEMSIZE];

for (i = 0; i < MEMSIZE; i++) {
    source[i] = i;
}

//Reset CCR and CNDTR register 
DMA1_Channel1->CCR &= ~0x7FFF;
DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR &= ~0xFFFF;
/*
* DMA configure:
* MEM 2 MEM: Enabled
* Priority: Medium
* Memory size: 32 bit
* Peripheral size: 32bit
* Memory increment: ON
* Peripheral Increment: ON
* Circular: OFF
* Direction: Copy from peripheral
* Transfer error IR: OFF
* Haft Transferred IR: OFF
* Transfer complete IR: ON
* Channel Enable: OFF
*/
DMA1_Channel1->CCR |= 0x00005AC2;
// Setting number of data
DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR |= MEMSIZE;
// Setting Peripheral address
DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)source;
// Setting memory address
DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = (uint32_t)dest;
// NVIC setup
NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
// Enable DMA channel
DMA1_Channel1->CCR |= 0x00000001;
```

**Update:** I tried using GPIO ODR instead of array address for memory, and thats works perfectly

Comment: Code looks OK to me. Is the DMA clock enabled? Did you check the register values in a debug session?

Comment: @Tagli Clock for DMA was enabled, i also checked registers value in debug, found no problem

Comment: `DMA1_Channel1->CCR = 0x00000000;` don't do this. According to documentation: "Bits 31:15 Reserved, must be kept at reset value.", you'd better clear it like this: `DMA1_Channel1->CCR &= ~0x7FFF;`. The similar situation is with `DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR;`. You are ORing, but you can't be sure what values were in this register earlier. Clear it like this: `DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR &= ~0xFFFF`. Make sure you've enabled DMA1 clock in AHB. How do you check `dest` content after the transfer?

Comment: @itachi I added dest to watch window and observe its value when simulating. Clock for DMA was enabled, CNTR value are correct. I also use stm32CubeMX to create a DMA Enabled project and work with it, but the array just does not copy

Comment: Be careful with what registers you watch in debugger. Some registers change their values when read and that can cause invalid execution. Also, you have a mistake here: `DMA1_Channel1->CCR &= ~0x77FF;`, it should be `0x7FFF`. Also, why do you setup NVIC if you don't use interrupts?

Comment: @itachi Just a typing mistake, sorry!. I intended to use interrupt, but the event didn't fired. I've tried using GPIO ODR instead of address for memory and that worked, looks like the problem is because of dest array address ? But the address is correct, i compare its runtime address and CMAR register value, no difference

Comment: What's the value of `MEMSIZE`?

Comment: Make sure buffers are not local variables that are out of scope when DMA is processing your transaction.

Comment: @itachi MEMSIZE is 320, source and dest array is defined inside int main, can it be out of scope ?

Comment: As long as you have some infinite loop at the end of your main function, then it won't get out of scope. You can always move your buffers to global scope and try with that, just to eliminate possible points of failure. You can also try allocating memory for buffer dynamically with `malloc`, so it's created on heap rather on stack, I don't think this make difference in this case, but no one will punish you for trying ;).

Comment: @itachi I have tried this already, but still no hope :) Maybe i will get a discovery board to test on it, to see if it work or not. anyway thanks very much for your help

Comment: No problem. If I have some time tomorrow, I will check this out on my board. And I really encourage you to use constants from CMSIS for configuration rather than writing raw hex values ;).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to detect the problem in your code, but I created a minimal example on *Blue Pill* board. I checked the values in `dest` array in a debug session. The code seems to work as expected.

```c
#include "stm32f1xx.h"

#define MEMSIZE 32

uint32_t source[MEMSIZE];
uint32_t dest[MEMSIZE];

int main(void) {

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN; // Enable DMA clock

    // Initialize the test data
    for (int i = 0; i < MEMSIZE; ++i) {
        source[i] = i;
    }

    DMA1_Channel1->CCR |= DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM // Memory to memory mode
            | (0b01 << DMA_CCR_PL_Pos) // Medium priority
            | (0b10 << DMA_CCR_MSIZE_Pos) // Memory size: 32-bits
            | (0b10 << DMA_CCR_PSIZE_Pos) // Peripheral size: 32-bits
            | DMA_CCR_MINC // Memory increment is enabled
            | DMA_CCR_PINC; // Peripheral increment is enabled
    DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t) source;
    DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = (uint32_t) dest;
    DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = MEMSIZE;

    DMA1_Channel1->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN; // Start DMA transfer

    while (1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code just does not work with the simulator, but works perfectly on the Blue Pill board. Look like i've found the problem :)